# Formula to copy certain rows to a new sheet in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula that will copy rows from one sheet to another sheet based on certain criteria (specifically, whether or not the row is highlighted). How would one go about doing this?

Comment: Check this our: http://ccm.net/forum/affich-30153-copy-rows-based-on-a-condition

Comment: Easier and better with vba.  Formulas would need to be array and based on a value in a column not a color.  Formulas in themselves cannot check the properties of a cell.

Comment: What's determining if a cell is highlighted? If it's manually done, then you'll likely need VBA. If it's a conditional format, you can use that condition to help determine what to do...

Comment: Definitely looks like VBA is the best solution.  As a general rule of thumb with excel, I only use formulas when the only thing that needs to change is the cell that the formula is in.  Copying cells on conditions is a little too involved for a formula.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using VBA. I had to use a yes/no cell at the beginning to specify whether or not to highlight a row, so that it would auto-update whenever anyone changed a value.

```
Sub Autosort()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets(2).Select
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).Clear
Sheets(3).Select
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).Clear
Sheets(1).Select
FinalColumn = Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
FinalRow = 1
For x = 1 To FinalColumn
    thisRow = Cells(Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row
    If thisRow > FinalRow Then
        FinalRow = thisRow
    End If
Next x

For x = 2 To FinalRow
    IsCompleted = Cells(x, 1).ValueThen
    If IsCompleted = "Yes" Then
        Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, FinalColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, FinalColumn).Copy
        Sheets(2).Select
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets(1).Select
    ElseIf IsCompleted = "No" Then
        Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, FinalColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, FinalColumn).Copy
        Sheets(3).Select
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets(1).Select
    Else
        Cells(x, 1).Value = "No"
        Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, FinalColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, FinalColumn).Copy
        Sheets(3).Select
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets(1).Select
    End If
Next x
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```